# Getting TS "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent" error after changing story structure

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I used to have such code in my story for Button component

```
const meta: Meta<typeof Button> = {
  component: Button,
  title: "buttons/Button",
}

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof Button>
```

Later I decide to change it to such structure

```
const meta = {
  component: Button,
  title: "buttons/Button",
} satisfies Meta<typeof Button> 

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>
```

And now I am facing issues with my stories, I get TS2590 error

[screen of error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqzJ3.png)

Here is full stories code

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { Button } from "components/Button"

const meta = {
  component: Button,
  title: "buttons/Button",
} satisfies Meta<typeof Button> 

export default meta

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>

export const Default: Story = {
  args: {
    children: "Пример кнопки",
    size: "large",
    variant: "contained",
  },
}

export const Loading: Story = {
  args: {
    children: "Кнопка в состоянии загрузки",
    size: "large",
    variant: "contained",
    loading: true,
  },
}
```

I think maybe the reason of that problem is the props of my Button component. They might be complex and so how do i fix that? I have tried changing TS version in VSCode but that did not help

```
import { Button as MuiButton, ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps, Box } from "@mui/material"
import { FC } from "react"
import { LinkComponent } from "types"
import clsx from "clsx"
import { Icon } from "components/Icon"
import { Flex } from "components/Flex"
import styles from "./Button.module.css"

type Size = "medium" | "large"

export type ButtonProps = (
  | MuiButtonProps<
      LinkComponent,
      {
        component?: LinkComponent
      }
    >
  | MuiButtonProps
) & {
  size?: Size
  loading?: boolean
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ loading, children, className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <MuiButton disableRipple={loading} className={clsx({ buttonLoading: loading }, className)} {...props}>
      {loading && (
        <Flex className={styles.loading}>
          <Icon name="loading" />
        </Flex>
      )}
      <Box className={clsx({ [styles.hiddenContent]: loading })}>{children}</Box>
    </MuiButton>
  )
}

export default Button
```